# install BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im running python 3.1.2 on my ubuntu 10.04

which version of BeautifulSoup i need to install and how?

i already download version 3.2 and run `sudo python3 setup.py install`
but doesnt works

thnx

EDIT : The error i get is :

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "BeautifulSoup.py", line 448
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: What's not working?  For help, you need to share the details of how it's failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only series of BeautifulSoup which works with Python 3 is [3.1](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.1.x/) However the author has abandoned it and will not release updates. You can read more about the problems [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html).

UPDATE: This is no longer true, BeautifulSoup 4 works on Python 3. You can install it with `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

`pip install BeautifulSoup` will install version 3.

Comment: That's not true: The current release is Beautiful Soup 4.1.3 (August 20, 2012). You can install it with pip install beautifulsoup4 or easy_install beautifulsoup4. It's also available as the python-beautifulsoup4 package in recent versions of Debian and Ubuntu.

Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.

Comment: I just installed it with `easy_install beautifulsoup4`. But when I import it with `import BeautifulSoup` it gives import error - `No module named BeautifulSoup`. What should I import if not that?

Comment: Version 4 has a different package name so you should do `import bs4` instead.

Answer (score 8):

I followed these steps to install beautifulsoup4 for HTML parsing.

- Download the Beautiful Soup 4 source tarball and install it with

  ```
  $ python3 setup.py install
  ```
- After that enter your python3 console

  ```
  $ import bs4
  $ from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  ```

The first statement will work while the second will fail. You have to change BeautifulSoup module into python3 format with the help of this command.

```
$ 2to3 -w bs4
```

3 After that you can run the test again, and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try [beautifulsoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/). It works for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Then just try with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```